# “Any of the rest of…”

Tags: nouns, interrogatives

Two members of a ten-member group are going to a conference. A person wants to know if anyone else from the group is going.

Is the following question naturally phrased?

“Are any of the rest of them going to the conference?”

If not, what’s the correct way to phrase it?

Answer (score 1):

That is a natural way to rephrase it.  Another natural way to say it is, "Is anyone else in the group going?"